# Is it possible to show urls in django including request type?

Tags: python, django, url, python-requests, django-urls

I want to have a list with all the url in a django project with the type of request(GET,POST,PUT,DELETE)

I already tried this

```
pip install django-extensions
```

and after this code on terminal

```
python manage.py show_urls
```

I get a list with all the urls, but it would be nice to have the request type aswell

Edit:

ruby on rails has a perfect example with rake routes

```
$ rake routes
          users GET  /users          {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
formatted_users GET  /users.:format  {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
                POST /users          {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
                POST /users.:format  {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
```

Comment: You can make all possible requests to a URL (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTION, ...). It is only the view itself that might guard against certain ones, for example by returing a 405 error.

Comment: url can take all the request type, it's only on how you handle each request type for that url

Comment: @LinhNguyen ok, but doesnt't django identify if the page needs a parameter for example?

Comment: need an id ? you mean parameter ? that on your side to handle if a parameter exist for that specific request

Comment: @LinhNguyen No OP means what requests are allowed on urls similar like `rake routes`

Comment: I'm not sure about Rails, but at least in Django URLs aren't declared *with their methods*. Only a URL is connected to a view. And the view *can* be written in different ways, such that it's not always knowable what methods it supports. So… the answer is probably *no*.

Comment: @deceze I see.. thanks anyway

Comment: If you use class-based views they will take appropriate (error) action for unsupported actions. For example, a FormView subclass supports GET and POST. It's up to you to add methods for the other request types if that makes sense for you.